# How to connect html variables to java (not js)

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms

I have a project where I am creating an html form and saving those variables.

I need to connect these saved variables to a java code so it can return an URL that is created with the variable. The java code queries a dataset and creates a URL for users to plug that into the internet to access data. I then need to take the URL from java and put it back to html.

I also saved the variables in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to learn at least Servlet and JSP after that submit your form to the URL of that servlet and as you can't save data permanently on the client-side you have to use any database along with JDBC now you are set to run the app.

**Learning these things is important:**

- Web Basics [Learn HTML CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)
- Java [Learn Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial)
- Servlet [Learn Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-tutorial)
- JSP [Learn Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-tutorial)
- JDBC [Learn Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jdbc)
- Database [Learn SQL Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

**Keep Learning**